# How to setup ReSharper not to be a pain

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

So we use ReSharper 9.0 Platform 6 on Visual Studio 12.0 Ultimate and it's really becoming a pain. Personally, I think it´s great and we are just missing something.

This "feature" (bug?) is too stupid to be intentional:
Example:

```
using Something.Anything;
using Something.Anything.Class;
```

Some time it works fine, but suddenly, without ANY reason, it does not find "Anything" anymore, but ONLY in the second one (followed by .Class).
If you hover over the first, it shows the namespace-information as expected. But then you hover over the second and it says it does not find "Anything".

What is this?

Comment: faced with similar kind of issue. repair with original setup. worked for me.

Comment: That looks like a static using statement.  That was added in C# 6 and isn't available in versions of VS before 2015, unless you specifically install an extension.

Comment: Oh okay. Strange enough it works most of the time, but sometimes it decides not to..